# CakePHP: changing default view instead of home.ctp

Tags: cakephp

As title, how can I change default view without placing home.ctp in apps/views/pages/ folder?

lets say, I want the default home page to show /views/other/index.ctp .

Where should I change the coding? which files does it involved? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Create an `OtherController`:

```
// app/controllers/other_controller.php
class OtherController extends AppController {
    public function index() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

and point the root route in `app/config/routes.php` to it:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'other', 'action' => 'index'));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34337525/cakephp-static-pages-without-entity-but-with-dynamic-content